# Sensing when a 12 V line with a low-side switch is closed (switch is on) using an ESP32

Tags: circuit-analysis, switches, buffer, esp32

I want to use an ESP32 to read when multiple 12 V low-side switches are closed. For that my idea was to wanted to split the 12 V line, connect a digital buffer and a level shifter from 12 V down to 3.3 V (https://www.ezsbc.com/product/ls3-level-shifter-and-buffer/). The LS3 is bidirectional and uses two CM5048 ICs and it shifts 3.3 V to and from 12..15 V.

My problem is that I can't quite wrap my head around if this even works or if this is the right way to do it.

Wouldn't the loop constantly be closed if I connected anything in parallel to the low side switch? Wouldn't that cause the unknown MCU that's outputting the 12 V to think the switch is engaged?

This is the circuit in question. I don't know what the MCU that all the wires are connected to does. It just outputs 12 V on the line where the low-side switch is closed.

[image: Circuit in question]

This is the simplified schematic for what I wanna do. The two voltage sources are just examples for the 12V line and buck converter I'll be using.

[image: own schematic]

Comment: "This is the circuit in Question," - not really a circuit. Some fancy colorful lines... it's hard to tell anything from it. But if you need to "sense" only, you don't need a bidirectional level shifter. Something simple like voltage divider or resistor + zener could work. But it's really required to see what's behind your "12V device" (i.e. real schematic or at least some sort of description) to give you a proper answer.

Comment: As @NStorm said, without exact details of what source and load the switches are switching, a good or best answer can't be given. Please edit this information into your question.

Comment: Sadly I don't know the inner workings of the 12v device. The PCB is also covered with a white layer to prevent reverse engineering. I just know it outputs 12v on the line where the low side switch is closed. So my assumption was it would output 12v to the ESP32 GPIO pin if I were to split out the wire into that and then the device wouldn't sense the low side switch correctly anymore or is my basic knowledge of circuits failing me here?
I will try to measure voltage and load to get the required information.

Comment: According to the "simplified" schematic, the 12V source will be shorted when SW1 is closed. By the way, you don't need to put a screenshot. Instead, you can create the schematic with built-in editor and insert is directly into the question body.

Comment: In the real circuit the schematic is a little more complex. The "12v source" is an MCU controlling a motorcycle dashboard and the low side switch is a switch which detects the gear the motorcycle is currenlty in.
Thanks for the tip with built-in editor!

Answer (score 3):

You can use the below simple circuit, which uses one diode and one resistor for each General-Purpose Input (GPI) pin on your MCU.

When the switch is on, LOAD pulls D1's cathode well above 3.1 V and reverse-biases it. GPI is pulled logic HIGH by R1.

When the switch is on, D1 conducts and clamps R1 and GPI down at approx. 0.2 V. GPI is a good logic LOW.

The circuit relies on you knowing that LOAD will pull the open switch terminal to 12 V or at least to >3.1 V, so LOAD it will not sink current through the diode when the switch is open.

I have used this circuit in a variety of equipment over a long time with no problems.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fHovBum.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Wonderful and simple circuit!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the 12V load pulls some current when S1 is closed, then you can use a current sensing amplifier to detect the closed state. Choosing a large gain like the INS212 is good since you only want to saturate the output to V+ (3.3V) and detect when current is passing through Rs sense resistor. You need to calculate the Rs value such that it meets the Vih requirements of the ESP32 input pin when the load current is present.

[image]